# matplotlib weirdness, it's not drawing my graph

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib

What happened is I followed this [demo](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/api/histogram_demo.html), I modified it to suit my needs had it working, changed it to use a function to draw two graphs but now it doesn't work at all using `plt.show()` or `plt.savefig()`

here's my code

```
import csv
import numpy as np

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab

# I converted excel to a csv file
data = [x for x in csv.reader(open('ASS1_Q1.csv'))]

question1 = {}
question1['males'] = []
question1['females'] = []
for x in data:
    if x[0].lower() == "male":
        question1["males"].append(float(x[1]))
    elif x[0].lower() == "female":
        question1['females'].append(float(x[1]))
    else:
        print "Not a valid dataline", x

def plot_graph(data, filename):

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

    n, bins, patches = ax.hist(np.array(data), bins=13, align='mid', facecolor='#888888')

    ax.set_xlabel('Speed in kph')
    ax.set_ylabel('Amount of Females')

    ax.set_xlim(min(data, max(data)))

    # plt.savefig(filename)
    plt.show()           

plot_graph(question1['males'], "ASS1Q1-males.eps")
#plot_graph(question1['females'], "ASSQ2-females.eps")
print summary(question1['males'])
print summary(question1['females'])
```

Can someone explain why this is happening? what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
```

The command

```
python -c 'import matplotlib; matplotlib.use("")'
```

will show you the valid string arguments that can be sent to `matplotlib.use`. 
On my machine, 'Agg' is listed as valid, though I get no output when this is set. If you are curious, you could just keep trying various options until you find one that works.

When you find the one that your prefer, you may also find it more convenient to set something like

```
backend      : GtkAgg
```

in your ~/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc instead of using `matplotlib.use(...)`.

Comment: oh I found the problem line 36, I have the brackets all wrong :/, don't know how that happened, should have explained my self better as It was drawing a white space for a graph instead

Comment: @Daniel, very glad to hear you've found the problem, even though my suggestion was off in the wrong direction. :)